# Is there any site about animals or nature?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently, I've been wanting to ask questions about termites since they've been swarming around my house. I decided to see if there was a site to ask about animals, and when there wasn't one, nature. There weren't either, so I wondered if there was one with a weird name that I wouldn't think of. So, is there any site like animals or nature would be?

If there isn't, would it be worth asking to make this a site on Area 51?

Comment: What were you interested in asking about, specifically? If you're trying to get rid of them, that's different than looking for general information about them.

Comment: @Catija just general information: how long does the swarm last, how long do they live, etc.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer your termite example, but is directed toward your question title. The only site I've found which covers broad interests about animals and nature is [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), which Snow's answer recommends. I added a comment there with more detail. I've followed targeted proposals at Area 51 and none has come to fruition, although I'm with you if you want to try again. Outdoors:SE expanded their scope to include a lot of those questions, so I hope you'll check it out and see if fits your needs! Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know what they are and how they live, there's [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) which has over a thousand [species identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) questions.

> Questions looking to find the name of a specific organism. Please include as much information as possible on location/habitat, size/characteristics and behavior. Ideally, you should provide images.

If you want to get rid of them, then it sounds more like a [Gardening & Landscape](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) question of the [pest control](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest-control) variety.

Answer (score 5):

There's also the [Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification) stack that has an active Animal Identification tag.

They'd probably tell you how to cook them too.

Comment: Hi Snow! Thanks for suggesting Outdoors:SE! I'm very active there, and it's excellent for people interested in [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals), and many aspects of nature. It's the only site I've found of its kind. In general, it's less scientific than Biology, but there are some technical questions, and the sites are complementary.  [Cooking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) related to certain outdoor activities is also on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your title, but it may answer your underlying question: there's [a site](https://diy.stackexchange.com) named both "Home Improvement" and "DIY" (URL is `diy.stackexchange.com`) for questions [about](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Questions you would typically ask a home contractor.
>       Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task.
>       Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.
>       National building codes (of any country).
>       Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.
>       Carpentry and woodworking.

It obviously wouldn't be a good site for general animal questions, but since you're asking about termites at your house, they might have just the specific expertise you're looking for?

By the same logic, you might try [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/). They're smaller and I don't know as much about them, but [acceptable topics there](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) include

> ...
>   gardening problems such as diagnosis and management of plant diseases and pests or methods for controlling weeds;
>   identification of plants — trees, shrubs, flowers, wildflowers — cultivated or growing in the garden or as a houseplant, or of animals that are affecting your garden or houseplants;
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

There are two sites where animals are on-topic.

The first is [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com). Last time I checked, that question was strictly about animals kept as pets, so your termites are likely to be off-topic.

The other is [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com). As always, however, be careful to do prior research before asking. Identification questions are currently allowed on that site, but there was a bit of [controversy](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/745/30567) around these.

The sample questions that you mention in your [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309841/is-there-any-site-about-animals-or-nature-that-has-a-weird-name-not-like-animal/309842#comment1011470_309841), "how long does the swarm last", "how long do they live" ... sound like very basic questions. I don't think these belong on Stack Exchange; if you can identify the type of termite, you should be able to find this on Wikipedia or in an entymology textbook.