# How can a site change the "tagline" that shows in the site dropdown?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button, tour, site-description

Over on The Great Outdoors, we have been [discussing our tagline](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/outdoorsmanship-really), inspired by [a post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309841/is-there-any-site-about-animals-or-nature?s=1%7C40.8461) from someone who couldn't find a site about nature. We settled on a new phrase

> For people who love being outdoors enjoying nature and wilderness, and learning about the required skills and equipment.

and it's been changed in our [tour](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tour). How can we change it in the dropdown now?

Comment: Have your mods pinged/emailed a CM to request it? That's the usual process.

Answer (score 5):

Contact the Community team (email is probably best) to request the change.  Link to any relevant meta posts that show community support for the change.  This blurb is called the "audience" and must begin with the word "for".

(We did this on Writing within the last year; that's when I learned about that wording restriction.)

Comment: Sure it's "audience" and not "site description"? As far as I know, it's the same description that appears in many other places, e.g. API, se.com sites list, and more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's what I was told when I asked about changing it on Writing.  I, in fact, described it as the blurb that shows up on the all-sites list and in network profiles.  I think it *originated* as the audience blurb on Area 51, though that's my guess.